# Web scraping with beautiful soup multiple files having each file as a column name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Python newbie here. I am trying to to get data from multiple page each page representing a column, for example see below

```
df = {
'country': [],
'values':[],
'units':[]
}
filesss = ['GDP.html', 'GDP per capita.html']
for filename in filesss:
if filename.endswith(".html"):
    variableName = filename.replace('.html', "")

    with open('indicators/'+filename, encoding='utf8') as filee:
        sou = bs(filee, 'lxml')
        if(sou is not None):
            table = sou.find('table', class_='table')
            if(table is not None):
                rows = table.find_all('tr', {'class': re.compile('^datatable-row')})
                if(rows is not None):
                    for i in range(len(rows)):
                        a = rows[i].find_all('td')[0].find('a')
                        if(a is not None):
                            
                            countryName = a.text.strip()
                            variableValue = rows[i].find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
                            unit = rows[i].find_all('td')[4].text.strip()
                            
                            df['units'].append(unit)
                            df['values'].append(variableValue)
                            
                            if(countryName not in df['country']):
                                df['country'].append(countryName)
```

Required result is somewhat like this

| Country | GDP | UNIT | GDP per capita | UNIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 2312 | USD BILLION | 2360 | USD |
| US | 2312 | USD BILLION | 2360 | USD |
| KENYA | 2312 | USD BILLION | 2360 | USD |

Comment: 'https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp-per-capita'

Comment: 'https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp',

Comment: Required files can be found at these urls

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use beautiful soup, so admittedly doesn't directly answer your question. However, even if verbose, it creates a simple solution using [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp-per-capita"

r = requests.get(url)
df_list = pd.read_html(r.text) # this parses all the tables in webpages to a list
df_gdp_per_capita = df_list[0]
df_gdp_per_capita['measurement'] = 'gdp_per_capita'

#repeat the same for second link

url = "https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/gdp"

r = requests.get(url)
df_list = pd.read_html(r.text) # this parses all the tables in webpages to a list
df_gdp = df_list[0]
df_gdp['measurement'] = 'gdp'

#combine the dataframes
df_gdp_combined = df_gdp_per_capita.append(df_gdp, ignore_index=True)
df_gdp_combined.head()
```

You can verify this works:

```
print(df_gdp_per_capita.shape)
print(df_gdp.shape)
print(df_gdp_combined.shape)
```